# Firefox will not permit me to change the default search engine

Tags: firefox

I just updated my computer and made sure all packages are up to date, but Firefox will not allow me to change the default search engine for the search box with the latest version of Firefox from the repositories.

I've tried all the normal ways to change it, but I can't set the default search engine from the search box. I can change from Google to DuckDuckGo for a single search in the search box, but I'm trying to set DuckDuckGo as the default and can't do it.

Is this a Firefox issue or an Ubuntu issue, or am I missing how to properly set the default search engine?

Comment: What happens when you go to Firefox's Menu > Preferences > Search, and in the "Default search engine" dropdown, choose DuckDuckGo ?

Comment: Sorry if I miss led - have changed default search engine in preferences to duckduckgo  -nothing changes - on start screen (firefox) the search box does show  DDgo but it is annoying to click all the time - did use the browser (not firefox) in ubuntu google came up first

Comment: Sorry but yes I done all the things listed in Answer 1

Answer (score 4):

1. Add DuckDuckGo to the Firefox one-click search engines.

   - Click the downward little black arrow in the Firefox search box (located next to the magnifying glass) to show the Firefox one-click search engines dropdown menu.
   - Click *Change Search Settings*.
   - Click *Restore Default Search Engines* (marked by a diagonal black arrow in the below screenshot).
   - Check the checkbox to the left of DuckDuckGo to add it to the list of one-click search engines as shown in the below screenshot.

   [image]
2. Change the Firefox default search engine to DuckDuckGo as shown in the below screenshot.

   - Click the downward little black arrow in the Firefox search box to show the Firefox one-click search engines dropdown menu.
   - Click *Change Search Settings*.
   - Change the Firefox default search engine to DuckDuckGo as shown in the below screenshot.

   [image]